# Input field which accept only number with maxlength

Tags: html, css

```
<input type="number">
```

I want take only number from input field with maxlength is 8.please suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with jquery.

```
$('input[type=number]').keypress(function() {
      if (this.value.length >= 8) {
          return false;
      }
});
```

you could replace the `'input[type=number]'` with either an id or class and add the id or class to the input field.

Comment: This does only work for numbers entered by keyboard. It would not work when pasting in a value.

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 allows to set min & max value of the input. If you want your input to have maximum length of 8 characters, just set max value to `99999999`. If you submit such an element with "invalid" value, browser will notice user about an error and won't let him submit the form. This will work when javascript is  turned off too.

```
<form>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="99999999" step="1" value="1">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```